# How to find filled seats in iOS Gamecenter match.participants?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

I'm writing a turn based iOS game using gamecenter and am having issues finding everyone currently seated in a partially filled game. How should I walk through my match's participants array and pull out the seated players? There will be between [1,8] players in the game at any one time and I am trying to populate a lobby with those that are filled.

Comment: I have to say, I have no idea why you are being voted down/voted to close.  The question seems reasonable to me, sadly I don't have quite enough experience with turn-based Gamecenter to answer.   You may want to add some sample code or something.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea why they would downvote this. It is really frustrating. I can't seem to reliably be able to determine who's really in my games.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two convenience methods I wrote for a 'GKTurnBasedMatch' category:

```
@implementation GKTurnBasedMatch (Convenience)

- (NSArray *) remainingPlayingParticipants;
{
    NSMutableArray *participants = [NSMutableArray array];

    // start searching at the current player
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.participants indexOfObject:self.currentParticipant];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.participants count]; i++)
    {
        GKTurnBasedParticipant *part = [self.participants objectAtIndex:(currentIndex + 1 + i)
                                                                        % self.participants.count];
        if (part.matchOutcome == GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeNone)
        {
            [participants addObject:part];
        }
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:participants];
}


- (NSArray *) remainingPlayingAndMatchedOpponents;
{
    NSMutableArray *participants = [NSMutableArray array];
    GKTurnBasedParticipant *localParticipant = [self localParticipant];

    // start searching at the current player
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.participants indexOfObject:self.currentParticipant];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.participants count]; i++)
    {
        GKTurnBasedParticipant *part = [self.participants objectAtIndex:(currentIndex + 1 + i)
                                        % self.participants.count];
        if (part.matchOutcome == GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeNone
            && part.status == GKTurnBasedParticipantStatusActive
            && part != localParticipant)
        {
            [participants addObject:part];
        }
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:participants];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Follow the tutorial in these two links and you should be all set..

[Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1) - [Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5509/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-2)

In short, every `GKTurnBasedMatch` object has an `NSArray` property called `participants` filled with `GKTurnBasedMatchParticipant` objects. You can loop through this array and see every participant in the game. It's smart to look at `status` property of these instances (of kind `GKTurnBasedParticipantStatus`) to see if a participant is actively seated or declined etc.. Hope this helps.

Comment: OOOPS - I just reread your question and figured that I answered a completely different question in my head - will edit in a few hours